# react doesn't render components with changes even when state changes

Tags: reactjs

As i followed the tutorial in react home page [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html). I wanted to modify the x-o game code to go forward and backward in a game. I am including the code below.

The history is recorded in a history list, pos is the index of current selection on the list.

As you can see I have three buttons: Reset, Up, Down. When you press Reset I reset the state. When you press up, I increase pos. When you press down, I decrease pos. I am also displaying pos to check.

The problem is pos is getting updated but the components are not re rendering. for ease of use I am including the heroku [here](https://whispering-mountain-49232.herokuapp.com)

What am i missing here?

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';


function Square(props){
    return (
        <div className="square" onClick={() => props.onClick()}>
            {props.value}
        </div>
    );
}

function calculateWinner(squares){
    const winners = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8]
    ];
    for(let i = 0; i < winners.length; i++){
        const [a, b, c] = winners[i];
        if(squares[a] && squares[b] === squares[a] && squares[c] === squares[a]){
            return squares[a];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

class Board extends Component{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            history: [Array(9).fill(null)],
            pos : 0,
            xIsNext: true
        }
    }

    handleClick(i){
        const current = this.state.history[this.state.pos];
        if (current[i] || calculateWinner(current)) {

        } else {
            const history = this.state.history.slice();
            const squares = history[this.state.pos].slice();
            squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? "X" : "O";
            history[this.state.pos + 1] = squares;
            this.setState({
                history: history,
                pos: this.state.pos + 1,
                xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext
            });
        }
    }

    clickReset(){
        this.setState(
            {
                history: [Array(9).fill(null)],
                pos : 0,
                xIsNext: true
            }
        );
    }
    clickUp(){
        let pos = this.state.pos;
        if(pos < this.state.history.length) {
            pos += 1;
            this.setState(
                {
                    pos: pos,
                    xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext
                }
            );
        }
    }
    clickDown(){
        let pos = this.state.pos;
        if(pos > 0) {
            pos -= 1;
            this.setState(
                {
                    pos: pos,
                    xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext
                }
            );
        }
    }
    renderSquare(i){
        let current = this.state.history[this.state.pos];
        return (
            <Square value={current[i]} onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}/>
        )
    }

    render() {
        let status ;
        const pos = this.state.pos;
        const current = this.state.history[pos];
        const winnerCal = calculateWinner(current);
        if (winnerCal){
            status = "Winner : " + winnerCal;
        } else {
            status = "Next Play : " + (this.state.xIsNext ? "X" : "O");
        }
        return (
            <div className="col">

                <div className="row justify-content-center">
                    <div className="board-row">
                        {this.renderSquare(0)}
                        {this.renderSquare(1)}
                        {this.renderSquare(2)}
                    </div>
                    <div className="w-100"></div>
                    <div className="board-row">
                        {this.renderSquare(3)}
                        {this.renderSquare(4)}
                        {this.renderSquare(5)}
                    </div>
                    <div className="w-100"></div>
                    <div className="board-row">
                        {this.renderSquare(6)}
                        {this.renderSquare(7)}
                        {this.renderSquare(8)}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row justify-content-center">
                    {status} pos: {pos}
                </div>
                <div className="row-fluid">
                    <button type="button" className="col-md-4 btn btn-warning" onClick={() => this.clickReset()}>Reset</button>
                    <button type="button" className="col-md-4 btn btn-danger" onClick={() => this.clickUp()}>up</button>
                    <button type="button" className="col-md-4 btn btn-info" onClick={() => this.clickDown()}>down</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
class App extends Component {

    renderHeader(){
        return (
            <div className="row justify-content-center">
                <div className="col"></div>
                <div className="col">
                    <h3 className="row justify-content-center"> Lets build a xo game </h3>
                </div>
                <div className="col"></div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    renderBoard(){
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col"></div>
                <Board className="col"/>
                <div className="col"></div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                {this.renderHeader()}
                {this.renderBoard()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Edits:

in handleClick() changed

```
const squares = history[this.state.pos]
..
history[history.length] = squares;
```

to

```
const squares = history[this.state.pos].slice();
..
history[this.state.pos + 1] = squares;
```

Comment: I put a breakpoint in the render function and it gets called everytime a button is clicked.

Comment: ok changed the question to something more accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is most likely functioning well. The problem is your history gets overwritten

```
const squares = history[this.state.pos];
squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? "X" : "O";
history[history.length] = squares;
```

leads to history[history.length] references the same object as  history[history.length - 1] and so on down to history[0]

Try using

```
const squares = history[this.state.pos].slice();
```

Comment: that solved the problem but, why should handleClick() which is linked clicks on individual squares affect what should be rendered. To be more clear when i click "up" or "down" what is the dependency to handleClick() which is a onClick method()

Comment: if you can say whats the importance of slice() there. It would be really helpful

Comment: You updated component state at handleClick() and state change triggered new rendering. When you call setState you change the state for entire board (which is rendered according to this.state.history).
The problem was caused by modifying same squares array that you got initially which made all arrays in history collection references to the same instance. In order to make each new history event a copy of the previous step I used slice to get a shallow copy